# Why does Chrome devtools complain that I should not use grid-column-end on an element with display: block?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, css-grid

I'm working with some css-grid formatted content.  I have a rule like the one below, applied to an element within the grid:

```
<some selector here> {
    grid-column-end: span 4;
}
```

When I do this, what I see in Chrome devtools (Chrome 108) is the following:

[image: screen clip of devtools showing disabled css rule]

Mousing over the "circle-i" gives the following message: "The **display: block** property prevents **grid-column-end** from having an effect.
Try setting **display** to something other than **block**."

I do not understand this message, and I have not been able to find any documentation that would explain it.  I can't see what other display type would be appropriate in this context. Is this a thing, or a Chrome bug?

Comment: This is happening to me right now and it's frustrating the hell out of me!

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug, given that it clearly does have an effect.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not certain whether this is a Chrome bug or not it's worth noting that the examples of using `grid-column-end` on MDN don't include any information about ensuring that the `display` property isn't set to `block` even though they're using `<div>`s in their example. You can see the sample code here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end#examples

Answer (score 1):

For that selector that could take more than 1 column, you should try setting one of the following options:

- inline-block
- inline-flex
- inline-grid
- inline-table

That worked for me.

Comment: Strange, it did not for me.  What is really odd is that when I mouse over the tooltip, it still says I should pick a display type other than block, even though the line above it literally reads "display: inline-block".

Comment: The question was: why? I for one would really like to know why!

Comment: It did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the selector is a ***direct*** descendant of the grid. This was casuing the issue for me.

Comment: This is a valid point, but was not the issue in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Chrome bug. I can replicate the issue in Chrome, but not in Firefox, with the latter being a more reputable source of styling hints for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and I just figured what was causing mine was the `width`, it was on the same element I wanted to apply the `grid-column-end` to, and once I took it out, that solved my problem to some degree. In your case, I would suggest first taking out the width entirely; if it works, you might have to find another way to apply the `clamp(250px, 100%, 400px)`. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try using grid-column: * / *; without using "grid-column-end"

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem, since I'm trying to create a rule for a field that should be four grid columns wide, but might have different starting grid points.

Comment: .boxes { 
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); {
         .grid-start {
           grid-column: 2 / 4;
         }
       }

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `display: grid;` set on the element, i have just figured out where my issue comes from
rule is you must set a display grid on the element first just like

```
el{
 display: grid;
 grid-column-end: span 4;
}
```